# Why does this rake task appear to not be running in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I tried running a rake task:

```
heroku run:detached rake some_task --app myproductionapp
```

Heroku told me to view the logs with `heroku logs -p run.8334 -a myproductionapp`

When I run that logging command in my console, nothing appears.  This means the task didn't run (or does it?).  On the professional dyno plan, I have 1 web at P_L level, 1 clock at 1x level, and 1 sidekiq dyno at P_L level running.  Do I need to setup a worker dyno?

To test out if it's something obvious:

So when I do a test with Mailinator and call the function I'm using to email a user one time, I get an actual "processed" message such as below and I see the email message in Mailinator.:

```
MyEmailer#send_this_message: processed outbound mail in 407.3ms
=> #<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x007gg91b5700a0>
```

When I try on production I don't get the processed message response, I only get the ActionMailer::Base::NullMail as below.

```
 => #<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x007gg91b5700a0>
```

*Mailing setup for staging:*

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['STAGING_HOST'] }
  # ActionMailer Config
  # Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  #config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  #config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  #config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address    => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port       => 587,
    :user_name  => ENV['MANDRILLUSER'],
    :password   => ENV['MANDRILL_KEY'],
    :domain     => 'heroku.com'
```

*Mailing setup for production:*

```
  # ActionMailer Config
  # Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  #config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  #config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  #config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address    => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port       => 587,
    :user_name  => ENV['MANDRILLUSER'],
    :password   => ENV['MANDRILL_KEY'],
    :domain     => 'productionapp.com',
    :enable_startls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the task? How can you tell that its not running? Are you expecting it to write to a log file?

Comment: @wpp I'm expecting it to send a few hundred emails via Mandrill and those emails aren't being sent (I should see a spike in the Mandrill dashboard).  They were being sent when I setup a staging environment.

Comment: I updated my answer based on what you added in your question, please consider mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi, if my answer was useful please consider select it as accepted answer, that's how the community works...

Comment: Hi Im still waiting for you to mark my answer as accepted, I spent some time answering you, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is very weird, but this may be happening due to an error in your task, check the whole logs `heroku logs -a myproductionapp`

For answer your question, you do not need any worker dyno, those are for background jobs, if you run the task manually then you do not need a worker, for example if you install "heroku scheduler" addon, then you can program your cron to run the task every amount of time without the need of a worker.

## Update

Thanks to the new details you added to your question, well in your production configuration you are missing the host, in your staging you have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['STAGING_HOST'] }
```

Well you need to add here your production host, you can add it manually:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://yourproductionapp.com' }
```

or using an environment variable:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['PRODUCTION_HOST'] }
```

make sure your environment variable has the correct value in your heroku production app.

Comment: I see something like `18 Feb 2016 2:00:01.184 2016-02-18 21:34:55.100786+00:00 heroku api - - Starting process with command `bundle exec rake myproductionapp` by random@example.com Context`  but no failure indication.  I have error notification thru Airbrake, but no errors appear.

Comment: Well check the email you are using, I had similar issue before and I checked that the email used for send the mails did not exist, well may be several reasons, without more information is impossible to help you.

Comment: Hi SsoulLesS, I updated the context in the ? above...for some reason it works on staging but not on production...

Comment: Well did you check your production keys? take a look to your environment variables and check that everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Well, all the ENV variables are the same in both, given that productionapp.com is on Heroku should I change the `:domain` key in config.action_mailer.smtp_settings to point to heroku.com as well?

Comment: in production.rb file `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://yourappdomain.com' }` that's it, also do the same with your `domain:` key it must be the same domain you are using in production app

Comment: you can also use an environment variable here instead of burn the domain name in your production.rb file...